# Java to Win32 Crypto API

Tags: java, c#, c, cryptography

I have the following public key generated from Java as RSA:

```
305c300d06092a864886f70d0101010500034b003048024100ab12b3ee64b85bdda7e9744df3210d9b0efc7fbd36385cd903a4f8ee51101bc9c4f0b23583ff090e7d61773e024cbbff4008037cba6538d1c70d865c948716e70203010001
```

I'm trying to import the key as the following:

1) Decode the string to byte array (**Key**)

```
public static byte[] DecodeKey(string data)
{
    int count = data.Length;
    byte[] key = new byte[count / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i += 2)
        key[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return key;
}
```

2) `CryptAcquireContext` using `Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider` and `PROV_RSA_FULL`.
3) Then call `CryptImportKey` with the key above and `key.Length`.

It returns:

> Bad Version of provider.

Comment: If this is Java why did you tag C#, C++ *and* C?!?

Comment: It's generated from Java, and want to import it in C or C#.

Comment: Implement your own version of RSA in Java and C#, its not that difficult

Comment: @user2179256 so what about C++?

Comment: What format is the RSA public key? @Sebastian L.: That is the worst you can do. Implementing cryptography is extremely difficult because you have to consider dozens of attacks, e.g. timing and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RSA key is in the [`SubjectPublicKeyInfo`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) format, which is what Java returns when you use the [`RSAPublicKey.getEncoded()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html) method. Java calls this format an [`X509EncodeKeySpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) for historical reasons.

This is an inconvenient format for .NET. You can examine the .NET classes to see what formats are most convenient. I suspect the most convenient format is the XML format. The following Java snippet will output an RSA public key in this format:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class RSAToXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey rsaPub = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("<RSAKeyValue>");
        System.out.print("\t<Modulus>");
        System.out.print(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(rsaPub.getModulus().toByteArray()));
        System.out.println("</Modulus>");
        System.out.print("\t<Exponent>");
        System.out.print(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(rsaPub.getPublicExponent().toByteArray()));
        System.out.println("</Exponent>");
        System.out.println("</RSAKeyValue>");
    }
}
```

This output can then be used to import the RSA public key into .NET as in the following C# snippet:

```
    public static void XmlImport()
    {
        var xmlPubKey = "<RSAKeyValue>\n\t<Modulus>AI0hSZ3hcfJHv1TPSIkT0XeW/HMPPFJMw4/aX5NxfhyVacpb5u6rucDztVNG1pXaBdya9OdO1+mGG250y+QuqP/70uu5QMcMEpCdp8xl0i+cUN9+fHDzse4XR/Kdrl3pKAefSR5QQX8xBScjTO+H+9fXVrrU9TQU6WXmahQnDwDJ</Modulus>\n\t<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>\n</RSAKeyValue>\n";
        var rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.FromXmlString(xmlPubKey);
        Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
    }
```

Note: This uses the .NET classes, not the Win32 CryptoAPI. There is almost no reason to still use the CryptoAPI anymore.